How to keep SSIS package running with ignore the file not exists in SFTP?
I create task in SSIS, there is task where I download file from SFTP server. The expected condition is no matter the file exists or not it will proceed to the next task.
I already test and if the file exists, it will proceed to the next task (success) but if the file not exists I got an error.
Can someone please help how to ignore if the file not exists? I mean I want the task keep running even though the file not exists.
I already try to modify my WinSCP script using if but it didn't work.

You didn't tell us much about your task, so we can only guess.
You mention "WinSCP script", so let's assume that you use "Execute Process Task" in SSIS to run the WinSCP script.
The "Execute Process Task" has a FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccess property. Set it to False, if you want the the package to continue, even if the script fails.
